# convert string of array to array of string

Tags: go, marshalling, unmarshalling

I have a raw string which is formed from array of strings like the one defined below

```
"['a','b','c']"
```

which i want to convert to proper array of string as below

```
["a","b","c"]
```

I am trying this on golang. However, i didn't succeed in getting this done. How this can be accomplished in go

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```golang
var s = "['a','b','c']"
ss := strings.Split(strings.Trim(s, "[]"), ",")
a := make([]string, len(ss))
for i := range ss {
    a[i] = strings.Trim(ss[i], "'")
}
out, err := json.Marshal(a)
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(string(out))
// output: ["a","b","c"]
```

https://go.dev/play/p/kQ0Up06K9zz